# Python Polygon Stocks API

Tags: python

I am learning to grab some news with dates filtering, say before 2022-03-01, from Polygon Stock API with below code:

```
from polygon import RESTClient
client = RESTClient(my_API_key)
response = client.reference_ticker_news_v2( ticker='TSLA', published_utc.lte='2022-03-01')
```

But below error is found:

```
  File "<ipython-input-57-bdc0fdfab609>", line 1
    response = client.reference_ticker_news_v2( ticker='TSLA', published_utc.lte='2022-03-01')
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

https://polygon.io/docs/stocks/get_v2_reference_news

I followed the parameters in above link but seems there is error with published_utc.lte (or other date range filtering parameters). The above code works when I replace the parameter with exact date parameter published_utc = '2022-03-01'. Can anyone help with this? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Bialomazur pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71634572/1431750), `published_utc.lte` is not a valid keyword argument name.

[From the Python API docs](https://github.com/polygon-io/client-python#query-parameters-for-rest-calls):

> Every function call under our RESTClient has the `query_params` kwargs. These kwargs are passed along and mapped 1:1 as query parameters to the underling HTTP call.

So use a dictionary to pass those as keyword args.

```py
query_params = {'ticker': 'TSLA',
                'published_utc.lte': '2022-03-01'}
response = client.reference_ticker_news_v2(**query_params)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't entirely understand where the problem is here. The second line of code is **syntactically wrong** as the error message shows.

`published_utc.lte` is not a valid **keyword argument name**. **Keyword arguments** must be **valid identifiers**. You should read up in the Python docs on this basic part of the syntactical rules of **Python**.

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html

https://realpython.com/python-keywords/